# Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, liquibase

I want to create mysql person table with liquibase. But I'm getting one error so

> Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

**db.changelog-master.yaml**

```
databaseChangeLog:
  -includeAll:
    path: db/changelog/v-0.1/
```

**20201015-01-create-person-table.yaml**

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 20201015-01
      author: nursultankhalilov
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: persons
            columns:
              - column:
                name: person_id
                type: bigint
                autoIncrement: true
                constraints:
                  primaryKey: true
                  primaryKeyName: person_pk
                  nullable: false
              - column:
                name: person_name
                type: VARCHAR(255)
                constraints:
                  nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: person_surname
                  type: VARCHAR(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
```

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/person
    username: user
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true

  liquibase:
    changeLog: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help

Comment: Could you confirm that db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml is the relative location of the yaml file from the application.yaml?  Are you using maven around your springboot application?

Comment: I am using gradle around my application